# The way to fill Longtitude an Latitude fields for customer entities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, geocoding

I have got in my Dynamics ca. 10000 contacts and I want to fill for all of them Longtitude and Latitude fields. Then I wish, this fileds will be automaticaly updated on  address changing  (and filled after creation of a new record). Is threre any plugin for that? Or can I do it self progrmmatically, using crm 2011 SDK in my client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a plugin on `Create` and `Update` messages that will convert the contact address to Longitude and Latitude.

You need to use a Geocoding API, you can use Bing Maps

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx

or Google Maps

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Comment: http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2012/12/20/geocoding-dynamics-crm-data-with-bing-maps.aspx This link might help.

Comment: Note, that there are licenses and costs associated with those technologies (at least Google).

Comment: Google has a free license, but the requests are limited for such an account.

Comment: More info about the licensing options : https://developers.google.com/maps/licensing

Comment: You'd also probably want to create a quick console app or workflow to go through and populate the current contacts.

Comment: To work around the licensing restrictions, you could try [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) (I work there) -- it starts free and there's none of those licensing restrictions (though the accuracy isn't quite as good, I'll admit).